# Combination hover effect not working

Tags: css

I simply want `.work-description` to have a bottom border also when `.project-link` is hovered.

```
.work-description { padding-top:50px; width:50%; margin:0 auto;}

.project-link { font-size:3em; text-decoration:none; }

.project-link:hover {  border-bottom: 3px solid #000; }

.project-link:hover + .work-description {
 border-bottom: 3px solid #000;}
```

Comment: Please provide your html as well

Comment: This looks fine to me but note that `+` selects just one `.work-description` element immediately after the `.project-link` element that's being hovered. Might try `~` instead of `+`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you are aware that the `+` is **referred to as an adjacent selector. It will select only the element that is immediately preceded by the former element. In this case, the element having `work-description` class has to immediately after the `project-link` class.**

If you have the right html (as shown below in the example), your code just works fine.

```css
.work-description {
    padding-top:50px;
    width:50%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.project-link {
    font-size:3em;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.project-link:hover {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
}
.project-link:hover + .work-description {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="abcd" class="project-link">
<div class="work-description">some random text here</div>
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: This is what I have in my html (https://jsfiddle.net/nekLkzpb/). `work-description` does follow `.project-link` but maybe it doesn't like headers?